# Composer Continue With Error Code

Tags: php, shell, composer-php

With composer I am trying to automatically format code but when php-cs-fixer fixes one of the directories it will exit with a code other than 0 and won't continue fixing the rest. Is there a way to tell composer to continue when there is an exit code other than 0?

composer.json:

```
"csf": [
  "php-cs-fixer fix models/",
  "php-cs-fixer fix config/",
  "php-cs-fixer fix controllers/",
  "php-cs-fixer fix test/"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Define fixing paths in `.php_cs` config file instead, eg"

```
return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setFinder(
        PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
            ->in([
                __DIR__.'/models',
                __DIR__.'/config',
                __DIR__.'/controllers',
                __DIR__.'/test',
            ])
    )
;
```